# Como quitar la ActionBar/ToolBar de mi aplicación Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Quisiera saber como quitar la parte que android studio pone por default al crear una app, lo que quiero quitar es lo que se muestra encerrado en rojo en la imagen.

[image: Quiero quitar la parte del recuadro rojo]

Por otro lado tengo este codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/marciano"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bienvenido"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="50dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

y en la vista previa me muestra la pantalla tal y como yo quiero que se vea, pero al momento de correr la aplicación en el emulador me lo muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me podría explicar por qué esta pasando esto?

Comment: En android studio puedes escojer el tipo de proyecto cómo blank, o agregar new activity...  te recomiendo antes en ponerte a programar directamente en Android mirarte tutoriales y irás aprendiendo las funcionalidades.

Comment: Es solo como recomendación, pero si cambiaras el titulo de tu pregunta a por ejemplo, `Como quitar el ActionBar de un app Android`, definiría mejor el contenido de la pregunta. Así si alguien necesita justo esto, podrá identificarlo antes. No te lo tomes a mal, es solo para que todos nos entendamos mejor y como recomendación. :)

Answer (score 18):

Se que la pregunta ya esta contestada, pero hace tiempo estuve mirando justo como ocultar o eliminar la `ActionBar` y recogí en un `PDF` los métodos más utilizados para ello (ya se han dicho en otras preguntas pero, a mi parecer, no se han explicado correctamente).

He pensado que le vendría muy bien a esta pregunta una contestación que recogiese varios métodos explicados.

Para dejarlo claro, la opción que se recomiendan utilizar siempre, es la del `Manifest.xml`, la **OPCIÓN 1**. En caso de no poder utilizarla, ya sea porque no les funciona o por cualquier otro caso, utilicen las otras opciones.

---

**OPCIÓN 1:**

En esta opción nos dirigimos al archivo `Manifest.xml` de nuestro proyecto y utilizamos el caso que necesitemos. En cualquiera de los dos casos debemos añadir en nuestro código la siguiente linea:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

- En caso de querer que en nuestra app no aparezca en ningún momento la ActionBar, es decir, eliminarla por completo de nuestra app, debemos introducir la linea anterior en la etiqueta de `<application.../>`, tal y como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo:

  ```
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```
- En caso de querer eliminar la `ActionBar` solo de una `Activity` debemos introducir la linea dentro de la etiqueta `<activity.../>`, como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo:

  ```
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```

  - En caso de querer eliminarla en varias `Activities`, se puede repetir tantas veces como se quiera el segundo caso.

---

**OPCIÓN 2:**

Esta opción es de forma programática utilizando la función `hide()`, pero existe una pequeña pega con la que estuve peleándome unos cuantos días. Por lo que en esta opción existen dos casos importantes:

- Si estas creando una aplicación compatible solo con la ultima versión de Android, es decir, que en la declaración de la clase de tu `MainActivity.java` ponga `extends Activity`, deber utilizar la función `getActionBar().hide();`. Justo como en el ejemplo:

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      getActionBar().hide();
  }
  ```

  }
- En caso contrario y el caso más común, en que en tu `MainActivity.java` ponga `extends AppCompatActivity`, deberás utilizar la función `getSupportActionBar().hide();`, como en el ejemplo:

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      getSupportActionBar().hide();
  }
  ```

  }

Hay que remarcar que esta función siempre se tiene que poner después de la linea de código `setContentView()`.

---

**OPCIÓN 3:**

Como ultima opción más común para ocultar la `ActionBar`, también utilizamos una función de forma programática y además, como existe una gran fragmetación de las versiones Android, debemos utilizar el caso que más se adecue a nuestra app.

- Justo como en la **OPCIÓN 2**, en caso de utilizar la ultima version en nuestra app, utilizamos la función `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`:

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
  ```

  }
- Y en caso contrario, de utilizar la compatibilidad de versiones, utilizamos la función `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
  ```

  }

Cabe destacar que esta linea **SIEMPRE** se escribirá por justo arriba de la linea de código `setContentView()`.

---

**OPCIÓN 4 (1 BIS):**
Una alternativa similar a la **OPCIÓN 1** es hacer un "Theme" para nuestra aplicacion que herede desde los themes del SO.
Esta opción nos deja abierta la posibilidad de personalizar mejor el diseño.

En el archivo styles.xml (res/values/styles.xml)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Y en el manifest en la etiqueta application agregar

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

el cual quedaría algo como:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Cabe destacar que actualmente al crear un proyecto nuevo desde Android Studio el código generado es del estilo de esta última alternativa (salvo el theme desde el que se hereda)

---

Con esta colección se puede elegir la forma que más les guste. Ademas, con estos ejemplos, nos hemos podido darnos cuenta de que siempre que utilicemos `AppCompatActivity` y queramos modificar alguna opción de la app, viene bien buscar también con la palabra `support`, que es lo que a mi me trajo de cabeza.

**NOTA: Se que me olvido de algunas formas, pero si queréis siempre podéis editar mi respuesta añadiéndola después de la ultima opción. Si todos colaboramos haremos de `StackOverflow en Español` una comunidad con recursos útiles.**

¡¡Mucha suerte a todos!!

Answer (score 3):

Para quitar el xml que Android Studio pone por Default es necesario poner esta linea de código en la etiqueta de `<Application>` del `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

tal y como se muestra en la sexta linea (Ejemplo) de este fragmento de código (Sacado del código del android Manifest de un proyecto):

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Eso es lo que respondí en mi respuesta, no? :0

Comment: Algo parecido pero tu código me marco error android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" pero de ahí tome la idea y le segui intentando hasta que pude

Answer (score 1):

Para el primer punto lo que deseas es remover la barra principal, lo puedes realizar aplicando el tema `"@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` a tu activity dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

o cualquier style que tenga las propiedades:

```
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Para el segundo punto el Layout no tiene ningún error, comentas que usas un emulador seguramente hay un problema con este, trata creando otro AVD.

Otra causa es que tu código podría estar modificando las propiedades del TextView por eso cuando se ejecuta se ve incorrecto.

Comment: Ya intente con otro emulador y el problema aun sigue, estoy usando una imagen 9-patch, y creo que los puntos para redimensionar la imegen es el problema, crees que tenga algo que ver.???

Comment: no, definitivamente no, la imagen esta bien dimensionada, para el texto usas un TextView verdad?

Comment: el 9-patch es marciano que colocas como background?

Comment: si estoy usando un TextView

Comment: si marciano es un imagen llamada, marciano.9.png

Answer (score 1):

Una forma es poner esta línea de código en el método onCreate de la Activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si esta usando la libreria de compatibilidad en tu activity, puedes removerlo programaticamente con:

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
 getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve el mismo caso, simplemente lo que hice fue quitar del AndroidManifest.xml la linea de android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
y con esto se me soluciono para la App que estaba diseñando, esa es una la otra forma que es mejor es irse a styles.xml alli modificar el código  que se encuentra en la primera linea de la etiqueta style parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" por parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionbar"
De esta manera como en el AndroidManifest.xml hace referencia la linea android:theme="@style/AppTheme" que se conecta al styles.xml permite modificar la parte visual de nuestro diseño de la App, espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

En tu método `onCreate()` añades la linea  `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

```
......
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.tu_activity);
    ..........
}
```

es importante que lo pongas antes del `setContentView` para que no de fallo la aplicación

Answer (score 1):

Debes ir al layout de tu actividad, que si has creado un proyecto nuevo, por default debe ser activity_main.xml y borrar esta parte:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Recuerda también borrar del onCreate de tu Actividad el siguiente código:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Eso sería todo, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

**Irónicamente di con la solución leyendo este post**.

### Paso 1:

Hay que borrar `android:label="@string/app_name"` del ***AndroidManifest.xml***

---

### Paso 2:

Agregar un tema que contenga *NoActionBar* del *style* *"@style/AppTheme"* en el ***AndroidManifest.xml***.

Por ejemplo voy a usar:

`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"`

Una vez realizado los cambios, el **ActionBar** desaparece.

---

Answer (score 0):

A mi me quedo asi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pacificris.usersapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.UsersApp">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.UsersApp.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SingUp"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.UsersApp.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserList">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: _¿Qué hace este código?_ Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación a tu respuesta. Pegar un bloque de código no es una respuesta de calidad. Considera también mencionar cómo tu respuesta aporta valor al contenido existente.