# problema al pasar de un fragmet a otro

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment

Hola el problema es que estoy intentado pasar de un  `Fragment` a otro

mediante un boton pero cuando toco el boton el otro `Fragment` se posiciona encima del primero , es decir se muestran los dos `fragment` en pantalla al mismo tiempo y y tendria que solamente visualizarce uno .

Lo que estoy buscando al final es   es cargar una vista con otro Toolbar.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando para pasar al otro `Fragment`

```
public class Fragmen2 extends Fragment {

Button Tboton,
        Lboton,
        Pboton,
        Dboton;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmen2, container, false);


    Tboton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.boton1fragmen2); /**boton que conecta el fragment 2 con la actividad temperatura */
    Tboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent Tboton = new Intent( getActivity() ,Temperatura.class);
            startActivity(Tboton);
        }
    });


   //Lboton =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.boton2fragmen2); /**boton que conecta el fragment 2 con la actividad distancias */


 //  Lboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       // @Override
    //    public void onClick(View v) {

          //  Intent Lboton = new Intent(getActivity() , DimensionFragment.class);
          //  startActivity(Lboton);

       // }
   // });

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmen1, container, false);

    Pboton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.boton3fragmen2);    /**boton que conecta el fragment 2 con la actividad power */
    Pboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DimensionFragment dimensionFragment = new DimensionFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmen2, dimensionFragment);
            //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }


    });


    Dboton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.boton4fragmen2);
    Dboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Dboton = new Intent(getActivity(),Dimensions.class);
            startActivity(Dboton);
        }
    });

    return  view;

}




}
```

Esto a si es como queda la vista

[image: Esto a si es como queda la vista]

Comment: Asegurate que el `.replace` está llamando al mismo ID del contenedor principal (`R.id.fragment2` es el mismo con el que cargaste el primer `Fragment`?). Si lo que quieres es cargar una vista con otro `Toolbar`, tu solución está perfecta. Solo que se va a ver como se está viendo ahora, para eso deber cargar tu vista en una nueva `Activity` y no como un `Fragment` ya que el contenedor del `Fragment` está jerarquizado de forma que tu Toolbar quede siempre encima.

Comment: @Andrespengineer si es exactamente lo que quiero hacer quiero cargar el Toolbar en otra vista pero ese Toolbar es el que genera el Drawer menu en android no encuentro como ponerlo en otra activity

Comment: La pregunta es, estas utilizando el primer toolbar para algo?, lo que puedes hacer es ocultarlo cuando inicializes el fragment con getActivity().getActionBar().hide() si es AppCompatActivity getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide(); y para volver a mostrarlo en el OnResume del activity haces lo mismo pero con .show(), aqui te dejo un link para que veas ciertas maneras de ocultar el toolbar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8237/como-quitar-la-actionbar-toolbar-de-mi-aplicación-android

Comment: @Andrespengineer era que queria seguir utilizando el drawer menu desde cualquier vista o actividad

Comment: Si pero es lo que te digo, solo tienes que jugar con .hide() y .show() del Action Bar, con el ciclo de vida del activity o fragment digase onResume() onPause() etc...

Comment: @Andrespengineer ok voy a intentar

Answer (score 1):

¿Seguro estás llamando al FragmentManager correctamente? Utiliza:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: la misma situacion con ese metodo